# 'Better' way to handle adding a record

Tags: c#, entity-framework

**Scenario:** I am using a helper class called 'OutputHelper' to add a new record to the table 'Output'. My 'Output' object contains the following:

- ShiftID
- Model
- WorksOrder
- LotNo
- Quantity
- ShiftHour

I do not want a record to be added if a record already exists with the ShiftID and ShiftHour of the record that I am trying to add.

The way I am achieving this currently is having the property 'RecordOutput' in the helper class try and add the record then return a string which I handle with a switch statement and provide feedback to the user accordingly.

This seems to be working fine but I can't help but think it's a terrible way of doing things. Can anyone provide any feedback and suggestions for improvement?

**Output helper class:**

```
public class OutputHelper
{
    public string RecordOutput(Models.Output output)
    {
        var shiftId = output.ShiftID;
        var shiftHour = output.ShiftHour;

        using (var db = new TestContext())
        {
            try
            {
                if (db.Outputs.Any(x => x.ShiftID == shiftId && x.ShiftHour == shiftHour))
                {
                    return "Exists";
                }
                db.Outputs.Add(output);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return "NotSaved";
            }
            return "Success";
        }
    }
}
```

**Code from button click on form**

```
 var outputHelper = new OutputHelper();

        switch (outputHelper.RecordOutput(output))
        {
            case "Exists":
                lblErrorMessage.Text = "Output already recorded for this timeframe";
                failMessage.Visible = true;
                break;
            case "Not Saved":
                lblErrorMessage.Text = "There was a problem saving this record. Please try again";
                failMessage.Visible = true;
                break;
            default:
                lblSuccess.Text = "Output record added to database";
                successMessage.Visible = true;
                ResetForm();
                break;
        }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of a string, return a boolean. This simplifies the testing on the outside. For the exception case, add the information you want and then rethrow and catch in the outer method. Also, if OutputHelper is only a wrapper for the database functions, you can make the class static, which would save you from having to create an instance of it in the click method

```
public static class OutputHelper
{
    public static bool RecordOutput(Models.Output output)
    {
        var shiftId = output.ShiftID;
        var shiftHour = output.ShiftHour;

        using (var db = new TestContext())
        {
            try
            {
                if (db.Outputs.Any(x => x.ShiftID == shiftId && x.ShiftHour == shiftHour))
                {
                    return false;
                }
                db.Outputs.Add(output);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new Exception("There was a problem saving this record: " + e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then the button click code becomes:

```
try
{
    if (OutputHelper.RecordOutput(output))
    {
        lblSuccess.Text = "Output record added to database.";
        successMessage.Visible = true;
        ResetForm();
    }
    else {
        //to keep from duplicating the code to display the error message
        throw new Exception("Output already recorded for this timeframe.");
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    lblErrorMessage.Text = e.Message;
    failMessage.Visible = true;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

#### String literals vs. constants vs. enums

I think that the biggest terrible thing that you are doing here is 1) using magic string literals that are not defined as constants. 2) using a string when you can use an `enum` instead.

```
public enum SaveResult
{
    Exists, NotSaved, Success
}
```

In fact, your current code returns `"NotSaved"`, while you check for `case "Not Saved":`. **That's why you should use constants or an enum!** Also, having success as the "default" case is not something I would recommend. It'd be better to assume failure unless success has been explicitly confirmed. Or even better, default is for "Oops, I forgot to check this case explicitly!", which would help you notice that you had written `"Not Saved"` instead of `"NotSaved"`.

In the end, an enum is the choice I would recommend here.

#### Catching

That said and done, I really question the `catch (Exception)`. In my experience, you should only catch the exceptions that you really need to catch. If the code would throw a `NullReferenceException` for example, that should propagate upwards and tell you that there is a serious bug in the code that needs to be fixed. Some Exceptions are just not meant to be caught.

#### Your question, and the database aspect

Besides this, I think that what you are doing here is reasonable. I think that it is  However, I would also like to point out that if you are using a RDMS here, then you might want to make your table have a primary key - or another unique index - over two columns: Both `ShiftId` and `ShiftHour`. Technically, that's the only way to really make sure that your table will not have duplicates over these values. Personally, I think it is perfectly OK to do a select-before-insert though. I think that is better than inserting without knowing if things go wrong or not, and catching the appropriate exception if things actually have gone wrong - i.e. a duplicate existed.

Be aware though, that after your `SELECT` query checking for a duplicate and before your `INSERT` query, there can theoretically be another query that just inserted a duplicate, effectively causing a race-condition. If such a situation would occur, the catch would still catch it of course (assuming you have the appropriate indexes in your table set up).

Comment: I agree on the catch, it is better to have your exceptions bubble up to the UI layer and have the UI layer display the exception. In fact, I would in the Data Layer wrap expected exceptions, then have the UI display the exception (knowing that you have no write permissions is much nicer than , "ERROR"). Also, NEVER use a string when an Enum can do the job. Finally, I would write bulk insert methods, as your code will do 3/4 queries over 2 or so round trips per insert.

Answer (score 7):

To piggy-back on @Simon André Forsberg answer...

Ditto, with a caveat:

> Personally, I think it is perfectly OK to do a select-before-insert though.

because as soon as you read records into memory the data is stale - some other query could have added or deleted a row w/ that key an instant after you looked. So to read from the DB then test for existence in memory then attempt a DB insert is problematic.

SO... do the checking in the database. Just send the record without checking first but do something like this in the database:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (select * from outputTable where shiftid = passedInShiftid)
    INSERT ....
ELSE
    UPDATE ....
END IF
```

And as noted by Simon, the above assumes `shiftid` is a primary key or at least unique. Of course you can use any combination of value(s) that defines a unique record in your table.

And of course this also means that when you read a record, read the key as well, whatever it is so the above sql can be done when sending records back.

Finally whatever field(s) you use for a key, DO NOT let those values be modified in the user interface once they are created.