# Reduce code complexity by applying ternary operator

Tags: c#

I have a condition in my code where I need to put a lot of nested `else if` statements.  However, I have managed to reduce some `if` cases by applying ternary operator, so that code looks nice and is readable. But still I am not satisfied with the result. I would like to remove rest of the `if` cases too and make the code better.

Can anyone suggest more optimization in this code block?

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SessionValues.AccessToken))
    {
        eventstatuscode = "logged";
        EventStatus eventStatus = rb.GetEventStatus();
        if (eventStatus != null)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(eventStatus.cancelDate))
            {
                eventstatuscode = DateTime.Parse(eventDetails.signUpDeadline) < DateTime.Now ? "expired": eventstatuscode;

            }

            else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(eventStatus.cancelDate))
            {
                eventstatuscode = eventStatus.onWaitingList ? "waitinglist" : eventstatuscode;
                eventstatuscode = eventStatus.onWaitingList == false ? "accepted" : eventstatuscode;

            }
        }
        else
        {
            eventstatuscode = DateTime.Parse(eventDetails.signUpDeadline) < DateTime.Now ? "expired" : eventstatuscode;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is the class EventStatus under your control or is it a framework class? Also what is a type of eventDetails?

Comment: Consider adding some context behind this code (the purpose of it).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Before deciding to use more ternary operators in your code, let's understand what if/else is about:

When the expression in the `if` clause is resolved to `true`, the block right after it is executed. If that expression is resolved to `false`, and there is an `else` block indicated, that block is executed.

An `else if` clause is needed if when the first condition is `false` there is still more than one execution option, based on a second(different) condition.

In your code you keep checking one condition, and then the opposite one, although this is totally redundant. if `(x==false)` is `true` then `(x==true)` is always `false`, and vice versa. Asking the same question and then the opposite is not only redundant, but also a maintenance risk, since you need to change the condition, you need to remember also changing the opposite one.

Also you should try to make all your conditions positive conditions - refrain from asking `if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(eventStatus.cancelDate))` - it is far better to switch the `if` and `else` blocks and ask `if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(eventStatus.cancelDate))` - the **!** operator ("not") is easy to miss, and may cause confusion. Of course, if only one block is implemented - no `else` block is better than no `if` block - leave the condition as it is.

To sum the above, a better code would look like this:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SessionValues.AccessToken))
{
    eventstatuscode = "logged";
    EventStatus eventStatus = rb.GetEventStatus();
    if (eventStatus != null)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(eventStatus.cancelDate))
        {
            eventstatuscode = eventStatus.onWaitingList ? "waitinglist" : "accepted";
        } else {
            eventstatuscode = DateTime.Parse(eventDetails.signUpDeadline) < DateTime.Now ? "expired": eventstatuscode;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        eventstatuscode = DateTime.Parse(eventDetails.signUpDeadline) < DateTime.Now ? "expired" : eventstatuscode;
    }
}
```

Now it is easier to see that the same line is indicated twice - the `"expired"` line. By combining the two `if` clauses - we can reduce that to only once (this is called being DRY):

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SessionValues.AccessToken))
{
    eventstatuscode = null;
    EventStatus eventStatus = rb.GetEventStatus();
    if (eventStatus != null && string.IsNullOrEmpty(eventStatus.cancelDate))
    {
        eventstatuscode = eventStatus.onWaitingList ? "waitinglist" : "accepted";
    }
    else
    {
        eventstatuscode = DateTime.Parse(eventDetails.signUpDeadline) < DateTime.Now ? "expired" : "logged";
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, you're right. One line was duplicated there, I gotta update my answer :)

Answer (score 12):

Let's take a look at the input and output you have in that code segment:

Input:

- `rb`, or technically only the `EventStatus` of rb, which becomes `eventStatus`.
- `eventDetails`

Output:

- `eventstatuscode`

Perfect, we have a clear input and a clear output, let's make it a method!

Using a method will allow us to use multiple return statements to simplify your code.

```
private String GetStatusCode(EventStatus eventStatus, EventDetails eventDetails)
{
    if (eventStatus == null || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(eventStatus.cancelDate))
    {
        return DateTime.Parse(eventDetails.signUpDeadline) < DateTime.Now ? "expired" : "logged";
    }
    // no need to check else as we return directly in the above check.

    return eventStatus.onWaitingList ? "waitinglist" : "accepted";
}
```

I reduced these two lines to one line, as you check for true first and then you check for false. I believe this should not make things different in your current code.

Another very important suggestion though:

**Make your eventstatuscode an enum**

```
public enum EventStatusCode 
{
    Logged, Expired, WaitingList, Accepted;
}
```

As [other questions on Code Review has proven](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/41572/better-way-to-handle-adding-a-record/), hard-coding strings can easily lead to mistakes. If you only misspell "waitinglist" somewhere, it will lead to bugs in your program. Using enums will allow such bugs to be caught by the compiler instead.

Comment: Just to add a comment. I would say the two ternary operations at the end are very hard (not quick) to work out what will be returned. Particularly since both are checking the property onWaitingList but one checks directly and other one uses a comparison with FALSE.

Comment: @Vojta You have a point there, as I wasn't sure whether it was a pure boolean or a nullable-boolean I didn't replace it, but it does look like it could be written `eventStatus.onWaitingList ? "waitinglist" : "accepted"`. Is that the reason for my down-vote?

Comment: I am sorry, I am not a C# programmer so did not know about nullable booleans. I guess it is a nice feature but I am pretty sure that it would cause a headache to C# programmer as well to work out the proper return type (it was the reason for down-vote). However a suggestion. After you proposed the Enum you could have a method getStatus() in the enum class and return the proper string instead of having the ternary operations. That should work for C# right?

Comment: @Vojta Unlike Java, C# enums can't have methods in them. So that's not possible. I am not very good in C# but I do know some of it, so I am not entirely sure if nullable booleans would cause any problems here. I will edit my answer.

Comment: I did not know that about the enums and method. Then what about the map with the key being the enum and the value being the status in String? Then you could use 
return map.get(eventStatus);  .

Comment: @Vojta Yes, that would be a good solution for converting the enum to it's string representation, or a simple `switch` statement could also work. *If* a String representation really is needed (I don't know if the string will be shown to the user or not with the code in the question).

Comment: I would say the switch would kinda not follow the purpose of having the code shorter. I generally try to avoid switches with the usage of maps (if you don't need super fast code), because then the code is short for choosing - just one line. And with addition of another options is just one line when filling the map. Plus if you need to choose/switch at more places you don't have to copy paste the switch - just use the map.get(). Just pointing out what I have experienced with switches and maps.

Comment: @Vojta Of course the `switch` statement should be placed within a method to prevent code duplication. That would make both the switch version and the map (called Dictionary in C#) version to be pretty much the same in both code required to set it up, extensibility, and code needed to call it. I consider them both as equally good options.

Comment: Just so it's said, you're declaring `eventStatus` twice -- once in the parameter list, and once in the body.

Comment: @cHao Thanks, removed the one in the body.

Answer (score 9):

Following on from Uri's answer, which was ...

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SessionValues.AccessToken))
{
    eventstatuscode = null;
    EventStatus eventStatus = rb.GetEventStatus();
    if (eventStatus != null && string.IsNullOrEmpty(eventStatus.cancelDate))
    {
        eventstatuscode = eventStatus.onWaitingList ? "waitinglist" : "accepted";
    }
    else
    {
        eventstatuscode = DateTime.Parse(eventDetails.signUpDeadline) < DateTime.Now ? "expired" : "logged";
    }
}
```

... you can condense that further using the ternary expressions you asked about, to remove the rest of the if statements (untested code ahead):

```
EventStatus eventStatus = rb.GetEventStatus();
eventstatuscode = (eventStatus != null && string.IsNullOrEmpty(eventStatus.cancelDate))
    ? (eventStatus.onWaitingList) ? "waitinglist" : "accepted"
    : (DateTime.Parse(eventDetails.signUpDeadline) < DateTime.Now) ? "expired" : "logged";
```

I don't recommend that though: because IMO Uri's version is almost equivalent and is easier to read.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the initial code, it seems like we are doing two things:

1. Check if the user is authenticated
2. Parse the status code

I have assumed the code is under your control. If not, most of the methods can be implemented as extension methods while keeping the syntax.

After refactoring, this is the top level code:

```
if (!Authenticated()) return;

var eventStatus = rb.GetEventStatus();
var deadline = DateTime.Parse(eventDetails.signUpDeadline);

eventstatuscode = eventStatus.GetStatusCode(deadline);
```

Checking for authentication is simply:

```
static bool Authenticated()
{
    return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(SessionValues.AccessToken);
}
```

The `EventStatus` class got a new method to parse the status code. There are four status codes of interest, and I like to be explicit on each one:

```
public string GetStatusCode(DateTime deadline)
{
    if (HasExpired(deadline)) return "expired";
    if (IsOnWaitingList()) return "waitinglist";
    if (IsAccepted()) return "accepted";
    return "logged";
}
```

The evaluation of each status code is extracted to individual methods. The whole class now looks like this:

```
internal class EventStatus
{
    readonly string cancelDate;
    readonly bool onWaitingList;

    public EventStatus(string cancelDate, bool onWaitingList)
    {
        this.cancelDate = cancelDate;
        this.onWaitingList = onWaitingList;
    }

    public string GetStatusCode(DateTime deadline)
    {
        if (HasExpired(deadline)) return "expired";
        if (IsOnWaitingList()) return "waitinglist";
        if (IsAccepted()) return "accepted";
        return "logged";
    }

    bool HasExpired(DateTime deadline)
    {
        return !Active() && Expired(deadline);
    }

    bool IsOnWaitingList()
    {
        return Active() && onWaitingList;
    }

    bool IsAccepted()
    {
        return Active() && !onWaitingList;
    }

    bool Active()
    {
        return String.IsNullOrEmpty(cancelDate);
    }

    static bool Expired(DateTime deadline)
    {
        return deadline < DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One technique that in my opinion makes the code way simpler is to exit as soon as possible (or "fail early", or "handle-the-error-first", if you'd like). This avoids having multiple nested blocks in your code, plus keeps your mind "clean" because you can be sure that, if the code followed under a given position, you can always be sure the right conditions have been met (and you don't have to worry about them any longer).

For instance, I would rewrite the code as

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(SessionValues.AccessToken))
   return; // fail early

// now we don't have to worry about SessionValues.AccessToken

eventstatuscode = "logged";
EventStatus eventStatus = rb.GetEventStatus();
if (eventStatus == null)
{
    eventstatuscode = DateTime.Parse(eventDetails.signUpDeadline) < DateTime.Now ? "expired" : eventstatuscode;
    return;
}

// now we don't have to worry about eventStatus
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(eventStatus.cancelDate))
{
    eventstatuscode = eventStatus.onWaitingList ? "waitinglist" : eventstatuscode;
    eventstatuscode = eventStatus.onWaitingList == false ? "accepted" : eventstatuscode;
    return;
}

eventstatuscode = DateTime.Parse(eventDetails.signUpDeadline) < DateTime.Now ? "expired": eventstatuscode;
```

Some people might not like this because someone has told them to avoid having multiple return points in a function. But for me, the above is much clearer. Every time I am reading a code that branches into an if-else, I have to keep both in my head, read the if, then go back, read the else as if the 'if' never happened, then start wondering what would be the output if the "if" conditions were met, then the else... back and forth.

This way I can read the if, and when I see it leads to a return, I know I will be able to forget that block to understand the rest of the function. One less thing to have in mind in order to understand the flow of the algorithm. I would apply the same to the ternary operation blocks, likely removing them if they don't lead to any reading improvements.

Plus, whenever I find myself in the middle of the function, I can always know that the bad conditions have already been handled (otherwise the execution cursor wouldn't be in that position in the first place). And if the execution shouldn't be there but is, I can quickly realize where the bug was (in the condition checks in the beginning of the function).

By the way, I hope I didn't introduce any mistakes in this refactoring as I didn't test it. I believe I might have, because usually I rely heavily on unit testing to get those refactoring artifacts!